# Motorway's exit in anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I’m new in anylogic modellization. I need to model a motorway's exit in which flows cars and trucks. Cars have a rate of 40 cars/hour and the truck have a rate of 30 trucks/hours.
Both cars and trucks are positioned in the same queue and they need to pay in the same motorway's exits. The problem is that cars and trucks have different rates of service so I need on the delay block to set 60 cars/hour and 30 trucks/hour. How I can model this.

Comment: you can't set a rate in a delay block...

Answer (score 0):

If by rate you mean a Poisson distribution of 60 cars/hr you can delay with exponential(1/60) hours to have the same effect. But I think what you need to do is to use a Source (Car Source) block and have cars and trucks enter with different rates rather than trying to delay them.

Anyways, if you need to use a delay:

If your agents have a parameter (e.g. isCar = true if agent is car and false if is truck) then you can put a shorthand java if in your delay "agent.isCar ?  exponential(1/60,0) : exponential(1/30,0)"

Comment: if truck and car are different agents, you have to use agent instanceof Car ? exponential(1/60.0) : exponential(1/30.0)

Comment: Sorry, I explain you better the problem. I need to model the exit of a motorway; There are two type of agents, the vehicles and the truck, and they have different rate of arrival (40 cars per hour and 30 trucks per hour). The two agents go in the same queue and next in the same resources (the resources are the machines to pay the motorway) but they have different service time (1 minutes for the cars and 4 minutes for the trucks).

Comment: I used two agents blocks (one for the cars and one for the trucks), one queue block and one delay block but I don't say how to modelize the different service time for the different type of agents. Thank you!!,

Comment: That is exactly what I and Felipe provided. If you have two different agents for cars and trucks follow Felipe's suggestion and put "agent instanceof Car ? 1 : 2" in delay box. Do a google search for "java shorthand if" and you will understand how this works. And please do not re-post the same question!